# Is it possible to find the sides of a parallelogram knowing the length of its short diagonal and internal angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Is it possible to find the sides of a parallelogram knowing the length of its short diagonal and internal angles?  The short diagonal measures 80 cm and its internal angles are 70° and 110°.

I tried law of sines but I need the angles on each rectangles, also I tried law of cosines but I couldn't. Obviously each internal triangle has angles 70°, $\alpha$, $\beta$ with $\alpha + \beta=110°$. But too many solutions, how can I pick the right one?

[image]

Comment: We do not have enough information to construct a unique parallelogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. A unique parallelogram *cannot be constructed* because other triangle of same subtended angle ( Euclid's thm ) can be found. All parallelograms have the same corner angles but different minimum distances between pair of parallel sides.

The sketch is not drawn to proper given angle size, the included angle is more towards 90 deg rather than 70 deg given.

[image]